# $B(n,z)$ "uniformly" converges to $A(n,z)$ which uniformly converges to G(z)?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

(1). Suppose that $\{A(n,z)\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ and G(z) are entire functions.  Suppose that for $z\in S(1/2):=\{|\mathrm{Im}(z)|< 1/2\}$ and any $0<\epsilon <1$, there exists a positive integer $N=N(\epsilon)$, such that for any integer $n\geqslant N$, we have  $\left|G(z)-A(n,z)\right|<\epsilon$. Thus we say that $\{A(n,z)\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ uniformly converge to $G(z)$ in the critical strip $S(1/2)$.

(2). Suppose that $\{B(n,z)\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ are entire functions. Supposed that for $z\in S(1/2)$ and any $0<\epsilon <1$, there exists a positive integer $M=M(\epsilon)$, such that for any integer $n\geqslant M$, we have  $\left|A(n,z)-B(n,z)\right|<\epsilon$.

***Question***
Do we still say that $\{B(n,z)\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ uniformly converge to $A(n,z)$ in the critical strip $S(1/2)$?

If not, what kind of name is used for the convergence described in (2)?

The reason I am not quite sure is because in (1) the uniform convergence target function, $G(z)$, is independent of $n$; while as in (2) the convergence target function, $A(n,z)$, is dependent on $n$, so it is a moving target.

Comment: Would the uniform convergence of $B$ not follow from the usual triangle inequality and then noting that for $\epsilon > 0$, $|A(n,z) - B(n,z)| + |G(z) - A(n,z)|$ converges uniformly with $\max(M(\epsilon), N(\epsilon))$?

Comment: @user137846 Yes, it is. And I am aware of this.  But I am just curious about the naming of the convergence of $B(n,z)$ to $A(n,z)$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @user137846. Thanks anyway.  I would like to separate my proof of $B(n,z)$ to $G(z)$ into two parts. Because it takes too long to put them together. So I am seeking a proper name for the part of $B(n,z)$ to $A(n,z)$.

Comment: In (2) it looks like you are describing pointwise convergence to $0$ of $A(n,z) - B(n,z)$ If you want a uniform condition, say "for all $z\in S$" at the end, not "for $z\in S$" at the beginning. In this case, just say $A(n,z) - B(n,z)$ converges to $0$ uniformly in $S.$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks a lot! This solves my problem.  Best

Comment: @zhw. In (2), I meant uniform convergence.  So I will follow your suggestion and put " for $z\in S$" at the end of the sentence in my manuscript.   Another question: if $S(1/2)$ is replaced by $D(r)=\{|z|<r\}$ and $M(\epsilon)$ is replaced by $M(\epsilon,r)$, can we still say that "$A(n,z)−B(n,z) $ converges to 0 uniformly in $D(r)$"?  In other words I am wondering  if $M$ in (2) can depend on the size of the compact domain $D(r)$ as well.

Comment: I think you can answer that one yourself.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for your hint! I will take it as a "Yes".  My major in college was not math, so I was not familiar with these kinds of convergence concepts.